# Python way to solve an eigenvalue problem

Tags: python, recursion, matrix

[image: recurrence relation problem i want to solve]

I have the system present in the picture. First the boundary conditions of the system, then the definitions of alpha and betas and then the recursion relation itself. What I know abou the system is that the variable g_l present in the alphas and betas has a g0 component inside. That g0 is the eigenvalue of my sistem.

Now trying to code this in python, I encounter the following problem. How can I let a free parameter g0 in my code when I build the matrix of the system? The code complains that the g_0 is not defined.

Comment: If you want to do "symbolic calculus" in python, ie calculus with variable names in expressions that haven't got a numeric value, then you should use library sympy. (But I don't understand very well your problem so I can't guarantee that this is really what you want to do)

Comment: See for instance this related question: [Matrix vector multiplication with parameters instead of values?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77832481/3080723)